# Passing a ViewController's view to be displayed inside a tableCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I want to attempt to pass a view into a tableCell subclass, and set this view inside the cell's content view.

My question is, if I do this, will the viewController's functionality be used if the user interacts with the view?

ie.  There is a switch in this view, that when triggered hides or shows some buttons.  This code is in the viewController, so if I pass the view into the cell's subclass, will it be triggered if the user flips the switch?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It seems like a very weird thing to do.

Comment: Long story short, I have a cell stored in a framework which cant handle xibs, but has to handle all manner of types.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom tableViewCell which holds an instance of that viewController.  The view controllers view can be a subview of that cell and any actions or outlets which are linked to that view will be handled by the view controller.

Comment: for what I need, the viewController could be different from case to case.  I need it to be more dynamic than that

Comment: True but they will still all be subclasses of UIViewController so you can create a UIViewController property and set a CusotomViewController class to it.